# How to stop slider to be cycled again in glide.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once a slider has finished all slides how to stop the slider after the last slide. Disabling moving forward but enabling moving backward.
http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/docs.html

Comment: tried `.destroy()` ?

Answer (score 3):

It's really simple, because it is buildin into plugin. You just need to set glide type to `slider`.

```
$('#Slider').glide({
    type: 'slider'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `rewind:false` the property you are looking for?

```
 glideOptions: {
  type: "slider",
  rewind: false,
  startAt: 0,
  perView: 5,
  
}
```